# "Variables are not available" when debugging in WebStorm

Tags: debugging, webstorm

Can somebody tell me why I can't debug with WebStorm?

It doesn't matter what code I put - the message *"Variables are not available"* keeps appearing in the *Variables* window.

[image]

Comment: It does not look like it's debugging anything at that moment. I mean -- looks like debug session is already over. Check "Debugger Console" tab for possible messages etc. It may have some exceptions/errors there.

Answer (score 1):

***Variables*** view is only populated when the execution is suspended on breakpoint. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/01/how-to-debug-with-webstorm/